# My rb2d gravity scale is set to 0 yet I still fall when I press the down arrow on my ladder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I'm making a ladder for my Unity game. Nothing much happens when you hover over it (that's normal). I want to freeze gravity by setting gravityscale 0 whenever the up arrow key is pressed (or w). Thankfully that works. Unfortunately though whenever I go down, gravity is still 0 but somehow my character falls back to the ground.

Here's my player code. Sorry the formatting is very bad; I just deleted the things that didn't have to do with ladders so you won't read irrelevant details.

```
 // ladder
    public float climb;
    public float climbspeed;
    public float gravitystore;
    public bool laddered;
    public GameObject laddercheck;
    public float upaxis;
    public xpositionladdercheck ladderx;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        ladderx = FindObjectOfType<xpositionladdercheck>();
        jumptimecounter = Jumptime;
        jumpscriptbetter = FindObjectOfType<BetterJump>();
       
        gameover = false;
        respawnscreen = FindObjectOfType<RespawnIntermission>();
        lives = 5;
        atkindex = FindObjectOfType<attackindex>();
        scale =transform.localScale;
        basicattackscript = FindObjectOfType<BasicAttack>();
        basicattacksupply = 0;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        gravitystore = rb.gravityScale;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
     

        
     
        
        horimove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
       
        
       
        if (isDead == false)
        {
            upaxis = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            anim.SetFloat("run", Mathf.Abs(horimove));
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && laddered)
            {
                jumpladder();
            }
            anim.SetFloat("run", Mathf.Abs(horimove));
            if (laddered && Mathf.Abs(upaxis) > .01)
            {
                rb.gravityScale = 0;
                climbm();
            } else if (!laddered)
            {
                rb.gravityScale = gravitystore;
            }
         if (laddered&&Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                StartCoroutine("jumpable");

            }  
           
            
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed * horimove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, rb.velocity.y);
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && OnGround)
            {
                jump();
            }
        }


    }
    IEnumerator jumpable()
    {
      
        laddercheck.SetActive(false);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.8f);
        laddercheck.SetActive(true);

    }
    void climbm()
    {
        if (laddered)
        {
            if (upaxis > .1f) {
               

            } else if (!laddered)
            {
                rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation;
            }
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * climbspeed * upaxis *Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = new Vector2(ladderx.ladderxpos, rb.position.y);
// the ladder.x things is just a script that gets the x position of the ladder but it works well so ignore that.
            

        }
    }
    public void jump()
    {
        
        
       
           
        
   
    }public void jumpladder()
    {
        
        
       
           
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {

                rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpforce * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
               
              

            
        }
       
    }
            
    }
   
    }
```

I set mass to the lowest (.0001) and still the same thing happens. I didn't include the ladderx position script or the sensing that I'm even on a ladder script but that's irrelevant to the question. It senses everything just fine and the xposition script works well as well.

Comment: You could try doing something where you didn’t change the gravity scale at all, but instead you’d clamp the velocity with a minimum y of 0, and a max y of 9999. Also when you are climbing you would add force instead of translating it to make a more realistic simulation (Untested). If it doesn’t work, put the velocity clamp in the `LateUpdate()`. Tell me if you want the code.

Comment: You might need a condition where there is no input to set your y component of velocity to 0. Even though are you setting the gravity to 0, there might be residual velocity left over from previous movement.

Comment: I don't know what's up. I tried that but I'm still just sliding down and falling off to the ground. My gravity scale is still 0 though in the inspector.

Comment: I don't now why exactly since i had my gravity scale 0 but I just had to set my Physics2D.gravity = new vector2 (0,0); whenever I climb the ladder and back to normal with a physgravity vector 2 variable whenever I leave or jump off the ladder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. For some reason I had to set the Physics2D.gravity to new Vector2 (0,0); whenever I climb the ladder. Then I made a vector 2 physgravity variable that stores the natural gravity and set it back to that whenever I leave the ladder.

```
public Vector2 physgravity;
physgravity = Physics2D.gravity;
        Physics2D.gravity = new Vector2(0f, -9.81f);
 private void Update()
    {
        if (!laddered)
        {
            Physics2D.gravity = new Vector2(0f, -9.81f);
        }
____________________ (later on in the script)
 if (laddered && Mathf.Abs(upaxis) > .01)
            {
                rb.gravityScale = 0;
                Physics2D.gravity = new Vector2(0, 0);

                rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);

                climbm();
```